# Geting "there are too many active webgl contexts on this page" error when adding TileLayer to map in openlayers

Tags: angular, frontend, cross-browser, webgl, openlayers

I try to add 6 TileLayer with GeoTIFF source into my map and is working but in some devises and some browsers it shows this error "too many active webgl contexts on this page, oldest context will be lost" and then "WebGl: invalid _Operation loseContext  context already lost"

The source i try to add is not big is about 20KB each

I use openlayers v7.1.0 and angular v12

This is the code, where putting the geotif image into the map

```
const sourceOptions: GeoTIFFSourceOptions = {
  allowFullFile: true,
};

this.map.setLayers([
new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url:
      "https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=" +
      this.key,
  }),
  className: "satellite",
}),
]);

// --------------------SET VIEW (FIT TO IMAGE)--------------------------------
const firstSource = new GeoTIFF({
sources: [
  {
    url:
      this.fields.filter((x) => x.number == fieldid)[0].url +
      this.imgDates[this.imgDates.length - 1].date +
      "/" +
      this.visualizations[0].url,
  },
],
sourceOptions: sourceOptions,
});

firstSource.getView().then((view: any) => {
this.map.setView(
  new View({
    projection: view.projection,
    center: view.center,
    zoom: 1,
  })
);
this.map
  .getView()
  .fit(view.extent, { padding: [150, 150, 150, 150] });
});

// --------------------SET LAYERS-----------------------------
this.visualizations.forEach((visualization: any) => {
const source = new GeoTIFF({
  normalize: visualization.normalize,
  sources: [
    {
      url:
        this.fields.filter((x) => x.number == fieldid)[0].url +
        this.imgDates[this.imgDates.length - 1].date +
        "/" +
        visualization.url,
    },
  ],
  sourceOptions: sourceOptions,
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
  className: visualization.name,
  visible: visualization.visible,
  style: {
    color: this.colorPlatter(visualization.color, ["band", 1]),
  },
  zIndex: visualization.zIndex,
});
this.map.addLayer(layer);
```

this is visualizations constant

```
    const VISIBLE = true;
    const NORMALIZE = false;
    var Z = 10;
    this.visualizations = [
      {
        name: "NDVI",
        normalize: NORMALIZE,
        url: "NDVI.tif",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        title: "ND",
        visible: VISIBLE,
        color: "NDVI",
        zIndex: (Z -= 1),
      },
      {
        name: "LAI",
        normalize: NORMALIZE,
        url: "LAI.tif",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        title: "LAI",
        visible: VISIBLE,
        color: "lai",
        zIndex: (Z -= 1),
      },
      {
        name: "SM",
        normalize: NORMALIZE,
        url: "SM.tif",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        title: "SM",
        visible: VISIBLE,
        color: "sm",
        zIndex: (Z -= 1),
      },
      {
        name: "laiCm",
        normalize: NORMALIZE,
        url: "laiCm.tif",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        title: "Cm",
        visible: VISIBLE,
        color: "cm",
        zIndex: (Z -= 1),
      },
      {
        name: "laiCw",
        normalize: NORMALIZE,
        url: "laiCw.tif",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        title: "Cw",
        visible: VISIBLE,
        color: "cw",
        zIndex: (Z -= 1),
      },
      {
        name: "laiCab",
        normalize: NORMALIZE,
        url: "laiCab.tif",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        title: "Cab",
        visible: VISIBLE,
        color: "cab",
        zIndex: (Z -= 1),
      },
    ];
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do not use `className` to identify a layer.  It has specific purpose which means only layers with that value can share a context or canvas.

Comment: Thank you Mike, i fix this and used `Layer.set("name", "satellite")` instead
not showing the error any more but it still doesn't show the image.
do you have any idea why this is happening.
I testing this in safari 11 and old browsers.